# Share Maven Dependencies with team members using Mercurial

Tags: maven, mercurial, shared-libraries, dependency-management

I want to share all the External Jars currently being managed by MAVEN with my other team members. I am using Mercurial as my SCM and i am trying to figure what is the easiest way to commit my entire project (include libs) to a repository so that my team members can clone and get running without severe eclipse configuration?

Comment: Maven is a really good match with Mercurial, for the precise purpose to keep the library dependencies jars out of the version control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven is there in order to help you retrieving libraries. So that, all you have to do is to commit all your files **including** the `pom.xml` (.hg should contains everything in `target`, and other unrelevant files)

Then your project members can pull the sources and run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (see [eclipse & maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html).

And finally import the project in Eclipse.

That was is they need sources...

If they only need the jars, you must put in your infrastructure a company repo that will handle your `deploy`ment using `mvn deploy`. Some information there [maven repo::Intro](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html), take special care at the `wagon` you could use (ftp, ...)

This way, when you're done with your devel and you have `push`ed your code, you just have to deploy the jar on your repo.

Doing so, your project member'll have to run `mvn -U eclipse:eclipse` or any goal to update their local repository with your lastest deployed version.

Comment: I'd also put the internal company repository in the parent pom, so your team members don't even have to edit their settings.xml to use it.

Comment: So essentially i just need to commit my pom.xml file as well as the mercurial .target file and my team members who have maven set up properly will be able to download the source and all jars ?

Comment: Yes, but not the .target file, the .hgignore file w/ all src/* plus any other relevant ones. What should ignored actually are, libraries em selves, and generated stuffs like target/*. Actually, .target is an eclipse file which is not needed by maven (and collaborators) in order to build your app. And moreover the fact that you can let maven deal alone w/ your eclipse project files generation.